# Need help in parsing column value based on value in other column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have two columns, COL1 and COL2. COL1 has value like `'Birds sitting on $1 and enjoying'` and COL2 has value like `'the.location_value[/tree,\building]'`

I need to update third column COL3 with values like `'Birds sitting on /tree and enjoying'`

i.e. `$1` in 1st column is replaced with `/tree`

which is the 1st word from list of comma separated words with in square brackets [] in COL2 i.e. `[/tree,\building]`

I wanted to know the best suitable combination of string function in postgresql to use to achieve this.

Comment: why do you want to store information which is already in COL1 and COL2?

Comment: For a reporting tool.  It's not very important.  But how to query is what I want to know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first extract the first element from the comma separated list, to do that, you can use `split_part()` but you first need to extract the actual list of values. This can be done using `substring()` with a regular expression:

```
substring(col2 from '\[(.*)\]')
```

will return `/tree,\building`

So the complete query would be:

```
select replace(col1, '$1', split_part(substring(col2 from '\[(.*)\]'), ',', 1))
from the_table;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/CMFZMP1728

Comment: how to press enter key in comment column.  as soon as I press enter key, it will post the comment !

Comment: Works fine in psql (9.6.2) but not in psql (9.5.1) -

select substring('the.location_value[/tree,\building]' from '\[(.*)\]');
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
                         ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 1: ...string('the.location_value[/tree,\building]' from '\[(.*)\]'...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.

Comment: That sounds as if you have turned set [`standard_conforming_strings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) to "off" in your 9.5 installation. It does work with a default 9.5 installation (the online example is using 9.5.3). I would **highly** recommend to set `standard_conforming_strings` to **ON** (which is the default, so you must have actively decided to use non-standard strings in your 9.5 installation)

Comment: Hi, thanks.  But I will not be able to do that because I don't have permission to do that.  Is there any alternative to query the result.  Thanks.

Comment: Follow the advice given in the "HINT" part of the error message (but you should _really_ ask the responsible people why they chose to deviate from the standard. That is **not** a recommended configuration)

Comment: I added one more \ in pattern (in begining) and it worked.  Thanks.
select replace(col1, '$1', split_part(substring(col2 from '\\[(.*)\]'), ',', 1))
from mytable where itemid = 25908;

Comment: But, issue is, the query doesn't return anything if the COL1 doesn't have the search string $1.  Is there a way to get the result if it has test without $1 or $2, etc.,

Comment: And I also would like to fetch 2nd word if text has $2.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work with any (`int`) number after `$`:

```
select  t.*, c.col3
from    t,
lateral (select string_agg(case
                  when o = 1 then s
                  else (string_to_array((select regexp_matches(t.col2, '\[(.*)\]'))[1], ','))[(select regexp_matches(s, '^\$(\d+)'))[1]::int] || substring(s from '^\$\d+(.*)')
                end, '' order by o) col3
         from   regexp_split_to_table(t.col1, '(?=\$\d+)') with ordinality s(s, o)) c
```

http://rextester.com/OKZAG54145

**Note**:it is not the most efficient though. It splits `col2`'s values (in the square brackets) each time for replacing `$N`.

**Update**: `LATERAL` and `WITH ORDINALITY` is not supported in older versions, but you could try a correlating subquery instead:

```
select t.*, (select array_to_string(array_agg(case
                      when s ~ E'^\\$(\\d+)'
                      then (string_to_array((select regexp_matches(t.col2, E'\\[(.*)\\]'))[1], ','))[(select regexp_matches(s, E'^\\$(\\d+)'))[1]::int] || substring(s from E'^\\$\\d+(.*)')
                      else s
                    end), '') col3
             from   regexp_split_to_table(t.col1, E'(?=\\$\\d+)') s) col3
from   t
```

Comment: How to use where clause in this query.  For example, if I need to mention, WHERE T.ID = 125;

Comment: @anandgp you can just continue the query with `WHERE t.id = ...` or with other parts of the select you want to use.

Comment: But it is failing -

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 3: lateral (select string_agg(case

Comment: I am doing this -

select  t.name, t.key_, c.col3
from    mytable t,
lateral (select string_agg(case
                   when o = 1 then s
                   else (string_to_array((select regexp_matches(t.key_, '\[(.*)\]'))[1], ','))[(select regexp_matches(s, '^\$(\d+)'))[1]::int] || substring(s from '^\$\d+(.*)')
                 end, '' order by o) col3
          from   regexp_split_to_table(t.name, '(?=\$\d+)') with ordinality s(s, o)) c
where itemid = 25909;

Comment: @anandgp you have a typo somewhere, my query works with `WHERE`: http://rextester.com/VSVKJ20607

Comment: There was escape string issue as below. But I corrected it with \\.

WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 2:   values (25909, 'Birds sitting on $1 and $2', 'the.location...
                                                       ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 6: lateral (select string_agg(case

Comment: But still it gives me below error.  I used your new query.

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 6: lateral (select string_agg(case

Comment: with mytable(itemid, name, key_) as (
  values (25909, 'Birds sitting on $1 and $2', 'the.location_value[/tree,/building]')
)
select  t.name, t.key_, c.col3
from    mytable t,
lateral (select string_agg(case
                  when o = 1 then s
                  else (string_to_array((select regexp_matches(t.key_, '\\[(.*)\]'))[1], ','))[(select regexp_matches(s, '^\$(\d+)'))[1]::int] || substring(s from '^\$\d+(.*)')
                end, '' order by o) col3
         from   regexp_split_to_table(t.name, '(?=\$\d+)') with ordinality s(s, o)) c
where itemid = 25909;

Comment: @anandgp It works on the example, which is PostgreSQL 9.5. Do not post your `psql` version, because that's just the client's version. It is not helpful in any manner. (use `select version()` to determine the version of the server).

Comment: oh ok. Thanks.  My version is -
PostgreSQL 8.4.20 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Comment: @anandgp that explains a lot. See my updated answer, but note that I can't test it with that old PostgreSQL. (But it *should* work: http://rextester.com/QVGLCF6870 )

Comment: No luck yet :(

ERROR:  function string_agg(text, unknown) does not exist
LINE 4: select t.*, (select string_agg(case
                            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @anandgp `array_to_string(array_agg(...), ',')` should be available in 8.4 instead of `string_agg(..., ',')` -- see the updated answer.

Comment: I tried this -
with t(col1, col2) as (
  values (E'Birds sitting on $1 and $2', E'the.location_value[/tree,\\building]')
)
select t.*, (select array_to_string(array_agg(case
                      when s ~ E'^\\$(\\d+)'
                      then (string_to_array((select regexp_matches(t.col2, E'\\[(.*)\\]'))[1], ','))[(select regexp_matches(s, E'^\\$(\\d+)'))[1]::int] || substring(s from E'^\\$\\d+(.*)')
                      else s
                    end, ',')) col3
             from   regexp_split_to_table(t.col1, E'(?=\\$\\d+)') s) col3
from   t;

Comment: getting below -
ERROR:  function array_agg(text, unknown) does not exist
LINE 4: select t.*, (select array_to_string(array_agg(case
                                            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @anandgp `array_agg` has only 1 parameter, please copy properly.

Comment: can we achieve this result by writing a small function which checks for any $n in passed text.  If there is no $n, it will simply return same text.  If there are any $n in the text, it will parse using multiple lines of code and return the value?  Thanks.

Comment: sorry, did not understand.  Can you please give me updated query.  Thanks.

Comment: @anandgp the subquery does exactly that. You can extract it to a function, but that won't increase neither performance, nor readability. -- the answer already has the updated query. See that in action: http://rextester.com/FHRU91685

Comment: ok.  Thanks works.  Thanks a lot.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: That works.  Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.